# how to find unmatched records with multiple match options

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

In MS Access. I have two tables. I am trying to find all records from Table 1 that do not have a match in Table 2.

```
Table 1

DP     FY     BS     RM     EX    
--------------------------------
21     1     0107     0    3000   
20     R     0201     6    3960   
12     3     0165     A    1111   


Table 2

DP     FY     BS     RD     LI
-------------------------------
11     4     0300    0     **11
21     5     0107    7     8**W
97     7     0819    0     2***
21     4     0107    7     2011
```

I need to concatenate Table1.DP + Table1.FY + Table1.BS + Table1.RM + Table1.EX and find any records in Table1 where there is NO MATCH in table2 on columns Table2.DP + Table2.FY + Table2.BS + Table2.RD + Table2.LI.

I also need no match on a few substrings of table2.LI where they will contain asterisks (not wildcards, actual asterisks).

The left 2 characters of Table2.LI could be asterisks, in which case I want to return that row in my result,

The middle 2 characters of Table2.LI could be asterisks, in which case I want to return that row in the result.

The last 3 characters of Table2.LI could be asterisks, in which case I want to return that row in my result.

So, if we were to concatenate the 5 key fields into one 12 character text field named Key, I want a query that will return all results from Table1 where

```
Table1.Key <> Table2.Key
Left(Table1.Key,8) + "**" + Right(Table1.Key,2) <> Table2.Key
Left(Table1.Key,9) + "**" + Right(Table1.Key,1) <> Table2.Key
Left(Table1.Key,9) + "***" <> Table2.Key
```

Basically, in those instances where there are asterisks in those substrings of Table2.LI, I do not care what is in Table1.EX in those positions.

How can I write a SQL statement to give me those results of an UNMATCHED query where I only get results of Table 1 where there is NO MATCH on those conditions in Table 2? Can I write the query to see the asterisks in the field as wildcards for comparison?

**Update**: I was able to solve the issue by replacing asterisks with question marks in the key field after building the key field. Then doing a left join using "like" on the join clause rather than equals. Now I have a newly discovered issue. There are two conditions where there are asterisks in the LI field but I do not want them converted to question marks because I don't want them seen as wildcards.

These are the conditions I DO want to change. Table2.LI =

```
**XX
X**X
X***
```

These are the conditions I do NOT want to be turned into wildcards: Table2.LI =

```
****
X*XX
```

(where X is any number or letter).

I was able to resolve the first by just adding a where clause saying where Table2.LI NOT CONTAINS("****"). Now I'm just trying to resolve the last condition. I need to check the LI field for an asterisk in the second position only, and ignore that case.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I found a way to do it by replacing the asterisks in table2.LI with questions marks. Then Access sees the question marks as wildcards and I'm doing a left join on key LIKE key (rather than =). where table2.key is null.

Comment: I'll add an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can first concant rows of Table_2 and `Cross Join` it with Table_1.
Please try this:

```
SELECT [DP]+[FY]+[BS]+[RD]+[LI] T2Key
into #tmp
FROM [Table_2]

select T1.* from [Table_1] T1
cross join #tmp T2
WHERE T1.[DP]+T1.[FY]+T1.[BS]+T1.[RM]+T1.[EX] <> T2.T2Key
and left(T1.[DP]+T1.[FY]+T1.[BS]+T1.[RM]+T1.[EX],8)+'**'+right(T1.[DP]+T1.[FY]+T1.[BS]+T1.[RM]+T1.[EX],2) <> T2.T2Key
and left(T1.[DP]+T1.[FY]+T1.[BS]+T1.[RM]+T1.[EX],9)+'**'+right(T1.[DP]+T1.[FY]+T1.[BS]+T1.[RM]+T1.[EX],1) <> T2.T2Key
and left(T1.[DP]+T1.[FY]+T1.[BS]+T1.[RM]+T1.[EX],9)+'***' <> T2.T2Key
```